# MySQL 2 rows returned, only 1 displaying content

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

So Im having an issue with MySQL returning 2 rows, but only 1 displaying in variable.
Not to sure why its not returning both

```
        $sql->bind_result($c_id, $c_location, $c_type) or die($mysqli_load->error);
        while($row = $sql->fetch()){
        $mysqli_load2 = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
        $query = "SELECT `badge` FROM `responders` WHERE `cid` = ?";
        $sql2 = $mysqli_load2->prepare($query) or die($mysqli_load2->error);
        $sql2->bind_param('i', $c_id);
        $sql2->execute() or die($mysqli_load2->error);
        $sql2->store_result();
        $rows = $sql2->num_rows;
        $sql2->bind_result($units);
        $sql2->fetch();
        $sql2->close();
        $mysqli_load2->close();
          echo '
          <tr>
            <td align="justify"><a href="viewcall.php?cid=' . $c_id .'"><u><abbr title="View Call">'.$c_id.'</abbr></u></td>
            <td align="justify">' . $c_location .'</td>
            <td align="justify">' . $c_type .'</td>
            <td align="justify">Rows: ' . $rows . ' ' . $units . '</td></tr>'; 
          }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only 1 displaying in variable"?

Comment: As in I have it echoing out the number of rows: 2 are returned, but it appears its only binding one of them to $units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop with the fetch() method:

```
while ($sql2->fetch()) {
  echo $units;
}
$sql2->close();
```

Comment: Perfect, I was silly to forget to loop through the $units and display each -> uncommon case of derpmode - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So here is the new updated code for anyone who would have a question similar to this:

```
        $sql->bind_result($c_id, $c_location, $c_type) or die($mysqli_load->error);
        while($row = $sql->fetch()){
            $mysqli_load2 = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
            $query = "SELECT `badge` FROM `responders` WHERE `cid` = ?";
            $sql2 = $mysqli_load2->prepare($query) or die($mysqli_load2->error);
            $sql2->bind_param('i', $c_id);
            $sql2->execute() or die($mysqli_load2->error);
            $sql2->bind_result($units);
                    echo '
            <tr>
            <td align="justify"><a href="viewcall.php?cid=' . $c_id .'"><u><abbr title="View Call">'.$c_id.'</abbr></u></td>
            <td align="justify">' . $c_location .'</td>
            <td align="justify">' . $c_type .'</td>
            <td align="justify">'; 
             while($sql2->fetch())
             {
             echo
             '#'.$units.' '; } echo '</td></tr>';
             } 
             $sql2->close();
             $mysqli_load2->close();
          $sql->close();
          $mysqli_load->close();
```